# Need help in understanding a censored word

Tags: meaning, translation, help

I've ran into a word that I can't seem to find/translate anywhere on the website and would appreciate if somebody can help me.

the word is: モ〇マス, and it was in the following sentence: モ〇マスをよろしく。

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**モバマス** is one of the nicknames of [アイドルマスター シンデレラガールズ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Idolmaster_Cinderella_Girls). The モバ part came from the fact that it was the first *iDOLM@STER* title hosted on the [Mobage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobage) platform. This nickname has became less popular after the title [gained popularity outside Mobage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Idolmaster_Cinderella_Girls:_Starlight_Stage) and [another *iDOLM@STER* title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Idolmaster_SideM) was released on Mobage. The "official" contraction of the game is デレマス now.

From what I could google, there is no other plausible possibilities, but if my explanation doesn't make sense, please provide more context. (What are they talking about? よろしく doesn't help much.)

Comment: I'm currently translating "THE IDOLM@STER" doujinshi and to be honest there is not much context to it. It's on the final page which has 2 bubbles on it. The text is as follows: みなさん楽しんでもらえましたか。コンプガチャがなくなってもモ〇マスをよろしくね。

Comment: @sparuj That's what we call context. モ〇マス placed near コンプガチャ is undoubtedly モバマス and I could have excluded other possibilities with 100% confidence. Was't your doujinshi created around 2012?

Comment: Yes. It was created 2012.

Comment: @sparuj コンプガチャがなくなっても refers to [this controversy](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%82%AC%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3#%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%82%AC%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E9%81%95%E6%B3%95%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C) that happned in 2012, and at that time, モバマス was seen as a "dangerous newcomer" by some existing Idolmaster fans. Whether your doujinshi features the "original 765 Pro" (Haruka, Chihaya, etc) or "Cinderella Girls", I imagine the author was hesitant to say モバマスをよろしく loud and clear, and that's probably why he masked a part of the title.

Comment: I see. Now it makes more sense. Thank you! I really appreciate you taking the time in order to help with this matter.

Comment: @sparuj Yeah, this would have been impossible to answer for anyone unfamiliar with Idolmaster (like most people, I assume). That's why the context is so critical.

Comment: @Leebo Making a reasonable guess is easy for anyone who has basic search skills (`モ○マス` has been used many times on the net and almost all of them point to this game). What's impossible (even for avid Idolmaster fans) is to have confidence about it. If there is no context, no one can rule out the possibility of [モンマス](https://twitter.com/monmas_jin), モリマス, etc.